# How can I select elements having a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-data-attribute

Find the `current` class from following, whichever data attribute tab has class and add append the `current` class to similar ID in below `div` with `tab-content`

```
<a class="projects_select tab-link" data-tab="tab-1" href="#tab1"> tab1 </a>
<a class="projects_select tab-link current" data-tab="tab-2" href="#tab2"> tab2 </a>
<a class="projects_select tab-link" data-tab="tab-3" href="#maps"> tab3 </a>
```

I have following `div's` having `tab-content` class.

```
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-1">Tab-1 </div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-2">Tab-2 </div>
<div class="tab-content" id="tab-3">Tab-3 </div>
```

tried:

```
$(document).ready(function($) { 
    $('.projects_select').find('current').attr(data-tab);
    $('.tab-content').addClass('current');
});
```

Comment: You forgot the `.` for your class selector. It's `.current` not `current` that would target a tag instead of a class.

Comment: `find('current')` is looking for `<current />`

Comment: `$('.projects_select').find('current').attr(data-tab);` so you are not doing anything with that it would return.... Expect to see something like `var foo = .....`

Comment: `.attr(data-tab);` seems like a variable name issue.  Or it's just missing surrounding quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The basic answer is simply a combined class selector, and you need to assign it to a variable:

```
var myId = $('.projects_select.current').attr(data-tab);
```

Then, to select a companion element using that:

```
$('#' + myId).addClass('current');
```

However, I suggest simplifying to use order (index):

```
var myIndex = $('.projects_select.current').index();
```

Then...

```
$('.tab-content').eq(myIndex).addClass('current');
```

This eliminates the requirement for IDs and data attributes.  If you have more instances of `.tab-content` on the page, include a class from an element containing both sets of elements:

```
$('.parent-element .tab-content').eq(myIndex).addClass('current');
```

https://api.jquery.com/eq/

Comment: This is really useful and looking for something like this.